# Colorbox - reset scrollbar to top of colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, colorbox

I have a page with 20+ colorbox's, all with AJAX HTML requests and lots of scrolling in each colorbox.

If I scroll half way down 1 colorbox, then close it, then open a different colorbox - the new colorbox opens at the same position as the last colorbox. But I would like each colorbox's scrollbar to start from the top.

Does anyone know of any code that resets the scrollbar positioning to the top on each open?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: Just updated the description - it was actually an AJAX request (loading content from a URL rather than HTML on the page). Regardless, I am still experiencing the same problem. I have tried to create a JSFIDDLE, but it does not allow me to create AJAX Colorbox's (only normal colorbox's). Is there a function I can call which resets the scrollbar position, everytime I open a new Colorbox?